# How to check Wi-Fi connection (SSID) when connected to MOBILE at the same time on Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, android-networking, wifimanager

I am having some strange issues when I want to verify, whether an Android device is connected to a specific Wi-Fi (identified by SSID) AND it has a MOBILE data network active at the same time.
It is also likely that my issue is connected to Android 9 (SDK 28), as I did not get any complaints from users with previous Android versions.

So here is what I have:

This is my main method, that should tell me whether the device is currently connected to it's target Wi-Fi:

```
public boolean isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() {

        if (isConnectedToWiFi()) {
            final String ssid = getConnectedSSID();
            if (ssid.startsWith(TRACKER_WIFI_PREFIX)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> YEAH, connected to Tracker: " + ssid);
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to Tracker, but: " + ssid);
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi!");
        return false;
    }
```

**Here are the helper methods:**

Check, whether we currently have a Wi-Fi connection:

```
    public boolean isConnectedToWiFi() {
        if (!isWifiEnabled()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "isConnectedToWiFi(): Wi-Fi is DISABLED");
            return false;
        }

        final WifiInfo wifiInfo = getConnectionInfo();
        if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "isConnectedToWiFi() --> wifiInfo is null!");
            return false;
        }

        final int networkId = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
        if (networkId == -1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnectedToWiFi() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi (networkId == -1)");
            return false;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isConnectedToWiFi() --> connected to Wi-Fi with networkId: " + networkId);
        return true;
    }
```

Check whether we are connected to any network at all:

```
    public boolean isConnected() {
        /*
           Returns details about the currently active default data network.
           When connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections.
        */
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnected() --> getActiveNetworkInfo() == NULL (no network connection)");
            return false;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnected() --> networkInfo.getTypeName() = " + networkInfo.getTypeName());
        }

        if (networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "isConnected() --> !networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()");
        return false;
    }
```

---

Now in my Broadcastreceiver, I want to handle the case as soon as I am connected to the anticipated device:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver connectivityBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> not the intent we are interested in");
                return;
            }

            if (wiFiConnectionManager.isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> CONNECTED to Tracker --> fragment.updateUiConnectedToTracker()");
                fragment.updateUiConnectedToTracker();
                openTrackerSocketConnection();
            } else {
                // Make sure we only show 1 AlertDialog per CONNECT attempt (= button press)
                if (userAwaitsResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> fragment.updateUiFailedToConnect()");
                    fragment.updateUiFailedToConnect();
                    userAwaitsResponse = false;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> SUPPRESSING UI update (since already done)");
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

However, when I test this on a Pixel 3 with Android 9 and let the mobile network enabled, I am getting this log:

```
D/ConnectDeviceFragment: connectButton --> onClick()
I/WiFiConnectionManager: isWiFiEnabled(): true
I/WiFiConnectionManager: isWiFiEnabled(): true
D/ConnectDeviceFragmentPresenter: connectToTrackersWiFi() --> use existing WifiConfiguration SSID: "TRACKER-pat08" (networkId: 141)
D/ConnectDeviceFragmentPresenter: connectToTrackersWiFi() --> going to disconnect from current network...
I/WiFiConnectionManager: disconnect() success: true
D/ConnectDeviceFragmentPresenter: connectToTrackersWiFi() --> in order to enableNetwork for networkId: 141
I/WiFiConnectionManager: enableNetwork() --> netId: 141 | success: true
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToWiFi() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi (networkId == -1)
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi!
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnected() --> networkInfo.getTypeName() = MOBILE
I/MainFragmentPresenter: connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> Assuming we have internet...
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToWiFi() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi (networkId == -1)
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi!
D/ConnectDeviceFragmentPresenter: connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> fragment.updateUiFailedToConnect()
D/ConnectDeviceFragment: updateUiFailedToConnect() --> creating but not showing yet (status might still change)
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToWiFi() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi (networkId == -1)
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi!
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnected() --> networkInfo.getTypeName() = MOBILE
I/MainFragmentPresenter: connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> Assuming we have internet...
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToWiFi() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi (networkId == -1)
D/WiFiConnectionManager: isConnectedToTrackerHotSpot() --> NOT connected to any Wi-Fi!
D/ConnectDeviceFragmentPresenter: connectivityBroadcastReceiver.onReceive() --> SUPPRESSING UI update (since already done)
I/ConnectDeviceFragment: updateUiFailedToConnect() --> run() delayed by: 5000
```

What am I doing wrong? My code works fine on any device, that has no mobile network enabled...

---

**Edit:**

I might have found the root cause:

```
    boolean openSocketConnection() {
        if (isSocketReady()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "openSocketConnection() --> isSocketReady() --> return true");
            return true;
        }

        //FIXME: Timeout if Wi-Fi AND mobile network are active --> force open socket on Wi-Fi
        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT);
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Log.i(TAG, "openSocketConnection() --> connection opened and input/output streams created!");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "openSocketConnection() --> IOException!", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So the new question is: how can I open a socket on the Wi-Fi connection (despite the active network will be mobile network). Because the Wi-Fi connection to my embedded device will never have internet, nevertheless I need to open a socket for communication...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I can somehow live with. The **root problem** in the end was that Android does open a socket on the default network, if you don't explicitly tell otherwise. And the default network is apparently always the one which has internet (which I learnt the hard way).

So here is the center piece of my new solution:

```
    private Socket getTrackerWiFiSocket() throws SocketException {
        final Socket socket;
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "getTrackerWiFiSocket() --> TRY getSocketFactory().createSocket()");
            socket = getSocketFactory().createSocket(TRACKER_API_ADDRESS, TRACKER_API_PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getTrackerWiFiSocket() --> getSocketFactory().createSocket() produced IOException: ", e);
            throw new SocketException(TAG + ".getTrackerWiFiSocket() --> create socket failed!");
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getTrackerWiFiSocket() --> socket: " + socket);
        return socket;
    }

    private SocketFactory getSocketFactory() throws SocketException {
        if (SDK_INT < 21) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getSocketFactory() --> SDK_INT is < 21 --> return SocketFactory.getDefault()");
            return SocketFactory.getDefault();
        }
        /*
            On API 21 and later, a socket that is NOT created with the Wi-Fi network's SocketFactory may try
            to connect via another network --> we have to make sure that always the Wi-Fi network is chosen
        */
        Network wifiNetwork = getWiFiNetwork();
        // FIXME: Find a nicer approach
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getSocketFactory() --> getWiFiNetwork() loop: " + i);
            if (wifiNetwork == null) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getSocketFactory() --> getWiFiNetwork() --> error during Thread.sleep");
                }

                wifiNetwork = getWiFiNetwork();

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "getSocketFactory() --> found Wi-Fi network socket!");
                return wifiNetwork.getSocketFactory();
            }
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "getSocketFactory() -> Could not find a suitable SocketFactory --> return default");
        throw new SocketException(TAG + ".getSocketFactory() --> could not get a SocketFactory!");
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private Network getWiFiNetwork() {
        for (Network network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {
            NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);

            // FIXME: Use another (non-deprecated) way to determine whether type is Wi-Fi
            if (info != null && info.getType() == TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getWiFiNetwork() --> found network with info: " + info);
                return network;
            }
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "getWiFiNetwork() --> Could not find the Wi-Fi network!");
        return null;
    }
```

If anyone has a better approach for making sure, that there is a `Network` object available to create a Socket from than my ugly loop with `Thread.sleep()` I am listening...